# Loading A message from an external database in Xcode

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, json

How would I go about loading a message from my website to display it as an alert on my iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can make a request to a URL like `http://mywebsite.com/statusmessage/` and it returns a string, you can get at that string like this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/statusmessage/"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *returnString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error) NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Remember to match the encoding argument of `+stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` to the encoding you're using.